# Quick command to assign a value to a variable and print it

Tags: r

Basically I would like one command which replaces the following two commands:

```
temp <- 5^2-2
print("temp")
```

I would like to see the result of the calculation assigned to temp without having to use the `print()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine it this way:

```
temp <- print(5^2-2)
```

Comment: nice, what a simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the whole expression in brackets.

```
(temp <- 5^2-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `.Last.value` function, like this:

```
temp <- 5^2-2
.Last.value
```

Hope it helps.